# OpenCL Mac OS compile from command line, openclc command not found

Tags: macos, opencl

It says [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Performance/Conceptual/OpenCL_MacProgGuide/XCodeHelloWorld/XCodeHelloWorld.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008312-CH10-SW7) that I can use `openclc` to compile from the command line, but when I do that, it says `openclc: command not found`, what shall I do?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5):

I found the program you're looking for in the following folder: `/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Libraries`. There you can call `openclc` and compile your `.cl` kernels.

Comment: Now it's compiled, but I'm getting 
`/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenCL.framework/Headers/cl_platform.h:349:18: fatal error: 
      'xmmintrin.h' file not found
        #include <xmmintrin.h>`

Comment: @ethanjyx I think this is a separated issue, unrelated with your original problem, so I think it's outside of the scope of this answer. You can try search for the error code or submit as a new question.